# Windows Prompt read and send text by COM port

Tags: php, serial-port, command-prompt, hyperterminal

I need a program to send and receive some text by a COM port. I would like to launch this by a exec command (command line).
I tried to view if Hyperterminal or putty can be used by command line but i can not find a solution.

This would be a workaround to send and receive text by a PHP webserver, I'm going to use the php exec function to run it.

Comment: Check [this](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3679-PHP-Communicate-with-a-serial-port.html).

Comment: seems to be only for linux

Answer (score 1):

I published two tiny command line applications called SerialSend and ComPrinter on my blog, which send and receive text via serial port. I'm not sure if they'll do exactly what you need since one only sends and the other only receives, but maybe you can get them to do what you want. They're completely free, you can download binary or sourcecode (they're really easy to compile), and they're both really easy to use.

Here are the links:

- [SerialSend web page](http://batchloaf.wordpress.com/serialsend/)
- [ComPrinter web page](http://batchloaf.wordpress.com/comprinter/)